# Woocommerce printing of product details - including all visible Attributes

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

The following section of the template provided to me, is trying to output the product attributes (name e.g. 'Voltage' value '240V', but instead all it's outputting is e.g. 'pa_voltage' and no value !?!

```
    <?php
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    if ( count( $attributes ) > 0 ) {
        ?>
        <table class="attributes">
            <?php
            foreach ( $attributes as $att ) {
                if ( $att['is_visible'] ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span><?php echo $att['name'] ?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $att['value'] ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>

        <?php
    }
    ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are getting the attributes only, but you need here the attribute variations like this:

```
$all_attr = $product->get_available_variations();
if (count($all_attr) > 0) {
    foreach ($all_attr as $attr) {

        foreach ($attr['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
            echo $key."<br>";
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```